# How to crawl JSON dictionary object into pandas dataframe regardless if value missing in dictionary?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, jmespath

I am making a API call and getting my JSON data like so:

```
import requests 
import jmespath
import pandas as pd
import json

url = 'a.com'

r = requests.get(url).json()
```

The object returned looks like this:

```
{'question': [{
   'response': {'firstname': {'value': 'John'},
    'lastname': {'value': 'Bob'}},
   'profile_question': [{
     'identities': [{'type': 'ID,
       'value': '1'},
      {'type': 'EMAIL',
       'value': 'test@test.com'}]}]}]}
```

I tried putting this into json.fr but I get error that it is not correctly formed json. How every I can crawl this object as is but not successfully for what I need.

I am trying to use `jmespath` library to crawl and want to pull out four pieces of information `firstname, lastname, ID, EMAIL` like so and appending the data into list:

```
    lst =[]

    fname = jmespath.search('question[*].response.{firstname:firstname.value}',my_dict)
    lst.append(fname)

    lname = jmespath.search('question[*].response.{lastname:lastname.value}',my_dict)
    lst.append(lname)

    email_path = jmespath.search("question[*].profile_question[].identities.{email:[?type=='EMAIL'].value}",my_dict)
    lst.append(email)

    ID = jmespath.search("question[*].profile_question[].identities.{email:[?type=='ID'].value}",my_dict)
    lst.append(ID)
```

I append into a list in hopes of creating tuples per iteration that I can push into a dataframe.

The list looks like this:

```
[[{'firstname': 'John'}],
 [{'lastname': 'Bob'}],
 [{'email': ['test@test.com']}],
 [{'ID': ['1']}]]
```

However when I crawl the dictionary with missing values like so:

```
{'question': [{
   'response': {'firstname': {'value': 'John'},
    'lastname': {'value': 'Bob'}},
   'profile-question': [{
     'identities': [{'type': 'ID,
       'value': '1'},
      {'type': 'EMAIL',
       'value': 'test@test.com'}]}]}],
   'response': {'firstname': {'value': 'John1'},
    'lastname': {'value': 'Bob1'}},
   'profile-question': [{
     'identities': [{'type': 'ID,
       'value': '2'}]}]}
```

causes my list to behave like this (I can not tell why):

```
[[{'firstname': 'John'}], [{'email': ['test@test.com']}], [{'email': ['1']},[{'firstname': 'John'}],
 [{'lastname': 'Bob'}],
 [{'email': [][][]}],
 [{'ID': ['1']}]]]
```

which causes the df to look like this:

```
firstname         lastname      email                ID
john                 bob        test@test.com        1 
john1                bob1       test@test.com        1
```

How do I crawl a JSON dict object as it comes in from the API, pulling out four pieces of data `firstname, lastname, email, ID` and appending into a dataframe like so? :

```
firstname         lastname      email                    ID
    john                 bob        test@test.com        1 
    john1                bob1                            2
```

More than willing to get away from `jmespath` library, and to add, the above dictionary has many more fields, I have shortened so only the key points and their indentation is listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well before anything the reason for the error is because the json object is missing quotes after ID.

```
 {'question': [{
   'response': {'firstname': {'value': 'John'},
    'lastname': {'value': 'Bob'}},
   'profile_question': [{
     'identities': [{'type': 'ID,
       'value': '1'},
      {'type': 'EMAIL',
       'value': 'test@test.com'}]}]}]}
```

It should look like this:

```
{'question': [{
   'response': {'firstname': {'value': 'John'},
    'lastname': {'value': 'Bob'}},
   'profile_question': [{
     'identities': [{'type': 'ID',
       'value': '1'},
      {'type': 'EMAIL',
       'value': 'test@test.com'}]}]}]}
```

From here you can use the json library to turn the json object into a python dictionary object with `json.loads()`. Once you fixed the json object, your code can look something like this.

```
import jmespath as jp
import pandas as pd


jon = {'question':
              [{'response': {'firstname': {'value': 'John'},
                             'lastname': {'value': 'Bob'}},
                'profile_question': [{'identities': [{'type': 'ID',
                                                      'value': '1'},
                                                     {'type': 'EMAIL', 'value': 'test@test.com'}]}]}]}


jsons = [jon] # list of all json objects
df_list = []
for json in jsons:
    try:
        fname = jp.search('question[*].response.firstname.value', jon)[0]
    except IndexError:
        fname = None
    try:
        lname = jp.search('question[*].response.lastname.value', jon)[0]
    except IndexError:
        lname = None
    try:
        email = jp.search("question[*].profile_question[].identities.{email:[?type=='EMAIL'].value}", jon)[0]['email'][0]
    except IndexError:
        email = None
    try:
        user_id = jp.search("question[*].profile_question[].identities.{email:[?type=='ID'].value}", jon)[0]['email'][0]
    except IndexError:
        user_id = None
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'firstname': fname, 'lastname': lname, 'email': email, 'id': user_id}, index=[0]))


df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. should each of the variables in the try be appending into `df_list`? Where or how is the `jsons` list being used?

Comment: The `[0]` is causing me to get error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`, not sure why.

Comment: Each of the variables are being appended to a new DataFrame. Each DataFrame has one row and is saved into a list. Then all the DataFrames are combined (concatenated) into one DataFrame in the end. As for your second comment can you give a stack trace of where exactly the error happens.

Comment: Here is the stack trace `fname = jp.search('question[*].response.firstname.value', lst)[0]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Since I am saving all my api calls in a list and passing that into `jsons` I think that is that is what is causing the stacktrace. When I pass a single instance of `r` the response from the API and removed the `[0]` from all variables in the for loop then stack trace changes too `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 20), indices imply (4, 1)`. I am wanting to iterate through the API calls if that helps.

Comment: One of two things are wrong. Either the JSON object isn't in the same format as the one posted in the solution,  or there is no firstname in the JSON object and the search query is returning None. For the first problem then you need rewrite your search query to properly find the firstname key. As far as the second problem you can change the except statement to read `except (IndexError, TypeError):` instead of `except IndexError`. This would be done to all of the except statements. Confirm that the first problem is not the cause to make sure your DataFrame holds all your data.

Comment: If it changes to a ValueError where does it occur?

Comment: value error happens here `    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'firstname': fname, 'lastname': lname, 'email': email, 'id': user_id}, index=[0]))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187333/discussion-between-safedev-and-rustyshackleford).